# Padding bug with framer motion switch custom

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I'm trying to make a custom switch component but there is some kind of glitch effect when the animation play. As you can see everything seems to move.

```
import React from "react";
import { clsx } from "@mantine/core";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

type Props = {
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: () => void;
  labelChecked: string;
  labelUnchecked: string;
};

export const AppSwitch: React.FC<Props> = ({ checked, onChange, labelChecked, labelUnchecked }) => (
  <motion.div
    onClick={onChange}
    animate={{ backgroundColor: checked ? "#68A4F5" : "#70707015" }}
    className={clsx(
      "cursor-pointer select-none shadow-md inline-flex items-center rounded-xl p-0.5",
      checked ? "flex-row-reverse" : "flex-row",
    )}
  >
    <motion.div
      layout="position"
      className={clsx("pl-3 pr-2 uppercase font-semibold text-black")}
      style={{ fontSize: "clamp(10px, 12px, 14px)" }}
    >
      {checked ? labelChecked : labelUnchecked}
    </motion.div>
    <motion.div layout="position" className="w-6 h-6 bg-white rounded-full" />
  </motion.div>
);
```

Also I'm trying to scale the font to scale down in a given space, seems not working well.

Thanks

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this using a
`<div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-start">` wrapping div around the content. I'm not sure why this works, but it works…